# "Set of a Set" getter in a javabean

Tags: java, jsp, set, javabeans, getter

I have a javebean linked to a jsp page and have to manage a SET OF A SET.

The javabean structure is something like this:

```
public class QueryManagement {
    ...
    private BigDecimal prob;
    private Set<Set<Axiom>> explanations;
    ...
    public void QueryExecute() {
        ...
        QueryResult r = new QueryResult();
        ...
        prob = r.getProbability();
        explanations = r.getExplanations();
        ...
    }
    ...
    public BigDecimal getProb() {
        return this.prob;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, from the jsp page I'm able to return `prob` with `<%=QueryManagement.getProb()%>` but I don't know how to return the vaule of a "Set of a Set". I tried a simple getter returning this.explanations, but it doesn't work. I know I have to return it recursively, but the doc I found at [the documentation I found about Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) can't help me. Can you explain me how to proceed and why?

Comment: You should do a `getExplanations` and in your JSP, work on that `Set` if you include the class...

Comment: you can use iterator to iterate set , means you have to use two iterator

Comment: @DamCx already tried, and it doesn't work. Tried with a simple     `public Set<Set<Axiom>> getExpl() {
     return this.explanations;
    }`

Comment: @santoshgore can you tell me how to do this? I haven't found the way to do the iteration of the set, and have no idea on how to do a double one here!

Comment: @GondraKkal please find the solution written in my below answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   public Set<Axiom> getExpl() 
   { Iterator itr1 = explanations.iterator();
        Set set ;
        while(itr1.hasNext())
        { 
            set = (HashSet)itr1.next(); 
        // second iterator for internal set 
        }                 
        return set ; 
   }
```

Comment: How should I use this code? Do I have to substitute my `explanations` declaration with yours? Then where should I place the rest? Sorry but your answer is a bit unclear, though I think it's close to resolve my problem.
Do I have to put it into the getter method? And how to recall it from the jsp file?

Comment: If you want  to get the only Set of explanations , then you can directly return using this.explanations . but if you want set of Axiom then write getter for Axiom and inside Getter iterate explanations Set for one time using iterator and it will reutrn the set of Axiom .

Comment: I can't understand still, I'm sorry.. What I want to be returned is the content of the inner set, which should be some strings. `this.explanations` returns me `[[SubClassOf( )]]` and it's no what I want. I didn't understand `write getter for Axiom`: Axiom is a type of variable, so I can't do a getter for it.

Comment: In this way you updated, and in the original first one also, it is not being done the instruction `explanations = r.getExplanations();`. 
Also my java file is named and I guess you wanted me to create a new javabean named after the first line: `public Set getBean` right? But I have code I can't modify (didn't write it myself) so I have to keep what it is in my first post. I'm still not understanding completely, so could you merge the two codes, @santosh?

Comment: Shouldn't I use the method toArray() to retrieve the Strings I need? So the thing to do is maybe to transform the collection of collections in an array, save it to a variable and then call that back to the jsp file?

Comment: which set of set you want to retrive?

Comment: If I understood correctly, the command `explanations = r.getExplanations();` puts strings into the most inner set, and I have to get it out from the jsp file. In your last edited code you created a new javabean, but I need to integrate your lines with the code I have (which I didn't write unfortunately). Since this Set is private, I'm pretty sure I need a getter to access to the values and let it be retrievable

Comment: yes , you have to define getter which iterate outer Set and gives you inner set

Comment: So then how can I print one after another the exlanations inside the set using something like <%=QueryManagement.getExpl()%>? Imagine I have to print one, do some other stuff/instructions, then print a second one, ecc

Comment: Is this fine?
`public Set<Axiom> getExpl() {
     Iterator itr1  = explanations.iterator();
      Set set ;
      while(itr1.hasNext())
      {
        set = itr1.next();
        // second iterator for internal set

      }
      return  set ;
    }`

Comment: When I compile this, I get the error `java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.Set`

Comment: Again, I get that error about conversion.. should it be void?

Comment: After cheching some stuff, I get `variable set might not have been initialized` and don't know why, since it is done inside the getter.

Comment: can you post your code and error which you are getting.

Comment: it's exactly the same as yours.. The relevant part of the rest of the code is up in the main post and the error comes from the return line in the getExpl method.

`public Set<Axiom> getExpl() {
     Iterator itr1 = explanations.iterator();
     Set set;
     while(itr1.hasNext()) { 
      set = (HashSet)itr1.next();
     }                 
     return set ; 
    }
`

Comment: Might be error is because of the explanations set value which is null.

Comment: It is difficult for me to debug the code. I'm using Eclipse, but check manually if the jsp page and the entire project proceed finely doing a compilation with Maven and then launching the jsp page with Tomcat.
So about your last comment, what should I change? Has the getter be modified in `public void getExpl()` or something else? I'm lost

Comment: Ok .if you are using eclipse then you can use breakpoints in eclipse to debug the code or if it is not possible then use SOP to print each value after each line. then you will come to know which value is wrong n which one is null.  getExpl method is getter method so how can you declare this method as void , as its returning set so your return type must be set.and there is error in your code that is why you are getting exception. can you print explanations value and check what value this variable contain.

Comment: I tried to search how to use the debug, but with a javabean I find it really complicated. I don't know how to refer the variables to print inside `explanations`, since it is a Set and not an array or list. Tried to put set type for the return also, with same error as before.

Comment: print variables like explanations , iterator1, set etc using System.out.println(); and you will  get come to know that where is null value present.if possible apply breakpoint in the method where you are getting error.